# Using Active Directory authentication for jmx

Tags: java, active-directory, jmx

I need to enable jmx with active directory authentication. Most of the examples indicate a user name and roles files to be placed on the server and use them for authentication.
I think it works ok, but I dont think it is efficient especially when you are dealing with considerable number of servers.

Is there any example on how to use active directory authentication for accessing jmx.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html#ldap

Comment: When i follow the instructions, and try to connect to JMX from 3rd party monitoring app, I get the below message on the 3rd party app.   
                                            An error occurred during communication with the JMX server. The server returned the following error: Cannot connect to JMX server Verify your credentials and check the connection properties; including the port number, IP address (host), and protocol.

Comment: What is your 3rd-party monitoring app?  Is it using LDAP?

Comment: We are using solarwinds

Comment: And it can use Active Directory for authentication.